# How to setup kitchensink example working on emulator or in android device?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha and phonegap. I want to package the [kitchen sink](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/kitchen-sink) example in apk file and run on emulator or android devices.

How can I go for it. Please give any link to get start with it. I have set up phonegap plugin already . Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Kitchen Sink</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha/resources/css/sencha-touch.css"
type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="sencha/sencha-touch.js"></script>
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript"
src="../../microloader/development.js"></script>
<!-- Uncomment following line to access PhoneGap APIs (not necessary to use PhoneGap to package web app) -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>-->

 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

project directory looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this?

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android

and also tutorial from PhoneGap:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Comment: Yes I have already read this but can't figure out the right way. Do you have any working example project? Thank You!!

Comment: the instruction from phonegap is easier to follow. Have you tried it? Which step are you stucked at?

Comment: I have a android debug key and installed the sencha sdk but don't get how to make configure file in step 3. In command `sencha package generate <configTemplate.json>` what is configTemplate.json?

Comment: it's the configuration file to be used with the packager. If you find it difficult then you should try the tutorial from PhoneGap as I've said. It's clearer.

Comment: Many thanks @Thiem can you tell me how can I use Sencha Architect 2 to easily build mobile apps? For now I am using AppLaud plugin and created the kitchensink project. But when I run it show only white screen. What i want is simple kitchensink app working on android device.  I have posted index.html file Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Sencha Architect. I develop everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There is a link of a PhoneGap-Beginners-Guide.pdf.This book contain all the basic concept of phonebook.

I hope it will helpful for you.

http://lecturer.eepis-its.edu/~yuliana/Android/Buku/PhoneGap-Beginners-Guide.pdf